# Firebase real time database - subscription .on() does not trigger on client

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a collection of notes in my Firebase realtime database. 
My code is set to subscribe to modifications in the ***/notes*** path of the database. 
When updating a note in the Firebase web console my client gets the updates, but when **another** client updates the note via ref.update() the data is not pushed to my client.

When updating in the Firebase web console, I am performing the update from one browser and watching the update in another browser.

How can this be? See code below.

```
export const startSubscribeNotes = () => {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    const uid = getState().auth.uid
    const dbPath = 'notes'

    database.ref(`${dbPath}`)
    .orderByChild(`access/members/${uid}`)
    .equalTo(true)
    .on('value', (snapshot) => {
      console.log('notes .on()')
      let updatednotes = []
      console.log('Existing notes', existingnotes)
      snapshot.forEach( (data) => {
        const note = {
          id: data.key,
          ...data.val()
        }
        updatednotes.push(note)
      })
      dispatch(setnotes(notes))
    })
  }
}
```

What I have noticed is that if I change my access rules in the Firebase database  I am able to get the updates, but can no longer restrict read access.

```
  "notes": {
    //entry-level access
  ".read": "
    auth.uid !== null //&& query.equalTo === auth.uid
  ",
```

I can then loop all notes and collect the ones I should only be able to read.

```
const uid = getState().auth.uid
database.ref('notes')
.on('value', (snapshot) => {
  const notes = []
  snapshot.forEach((data) => {
    const noteData = data.val()
    if(noteData.access){
      const authorArray = (noteData.access.author) ? [noteData.access.author] : []
      const members = (noteData.access.members) ? noteData.access.members : {}
      const membersArray = Object.keys(members)
      const allUsers = authorArray.concat(membersArray)
      const accessGranted = allUsers.includes(uid)
      if(accessGranted){
        const note = {
          id: data.key,
          ...data.val()
        }
        notes.push(note)
      }
    }
  })
  if(notes.length > 0){ dispatch(setNotes(notes)) } //Dispatch if not empty
})
```

How can I apply the access rules and still get the updates pushed to my client? 
I have checked that all clients can write to the database at ***/notes***

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Check the permission in the RULES tab in console. Seems like the 'another ' client  doesn't have permission to .write

Comment: Hi @MarkWalczak , thank you for the reply! The other client can write to the database. I can see the update in the firebase web console.

Comment: Try to add a `console.log("foo")` after `database.ref('notes')
.on('value', (snapshot) => {` and tell me if it works (= if "foo" pop for each update).

Comment: Hi @Curse! Thank you for the reply! That code works - since the access rules are bypassed - so yes "foo" gets logged as expected. :) However it is the first code example that I wish to fix - where Firebase access rules are set.